# Cannot change number format in Google Sheets, "Cell" tab is missing

Tags: google-sheets

I have Pixel 7 and Google Sheets (version 1.24.062.03.90). It seems like the option to format cells is gone. This is how it looks after I tap the Format icon "A≈".

[image]

It does not work like described here, because at point 4. there just is no "Cell".

> Format numbers, dates, and currencies
>
> To format numbers, dates, or currencies in a spreadsheet, follow these steps:
>
> 1. On your Android phone or tablet, open a spreadsheet in the Google Sheets app.
> 2. Tap a cell or range of cells.
> 3. Tap Format.
> 4. Tap Cell and then Number format.
> 5. Tap an option from the list. The format will be applied to your selected cells.

source: [Format numbers, dates, and currencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/adIeJ.png)

What I am trying to do? I want to customize the date format. I just don't get there...

Comment: Is it possible for you to clear Google Sheets' cache and data? This will allow to check if the issue persists as the app should acts as if it was used for the first time.

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio good tip. I did that after a force stop, app relaunch and even phone reboot. nothing helped. but a couple of days later it just looked like it was supposed to. problem vanished, mystery persists...

Answer (score 1):

For a more recent appearance with the **Format** drawer:

1. Scroll down until a row of cell formatting is visible, from left to right:

   - $ (currency)
   - % (percentage)
   - .0← (reduce decimal)
   - .00→ (increase decimal)
   - 123 (custom format)
2. Select **123**

[image]

---

For an older appearance with a drawer having **Text** and **Cell** tabs:

1. Select the **Cell** tab
2. Scroll to the bottom
3. Tap **Number format**

[image]